# How would the Python pipes module do a 'cat'

Tags: python, pipe

I am trying to do this in python:

```
cat foo | ssh me@xxxx hadoop fs -put - bar/foo
```

I have originally tried a check_call:

```
foo = 'foo'
subprocess.check_call(['cat', foo, '|','ssh',os.environ['USER']+'@'+hadoopGateway,'hadoop','fs','-put', '-', inputArgs.targetDir+'/'+foo])
```

which produces the error:

`cat: invalid option -- 'p'`

I have looked at the python pipes module documentation and played around with it in the shell, but I do not understand how to kick it off without an output file, like the example.

```
>>> t = pipes.Template()
>>> t.prepend('cat foo', '.-')
>>> t.append('hadoop fs -put - bar/foo', '-.') # what next
```

Clearly I am missing something.

Comment: Do you need to do this using the pipes module? I'm not sure how widely used that is, you might have more luck asking people how to do it with `subprocess`.

Comment: yes, that is what I have tried. I have also tried inline with the Popen but it gets hung up on the -put

Comment: Perhaps show us the `Popen` version, maybe someone can spot the problem with that.

Comment: Sorry I should have posted that the first time

Comment: add the `shell = True` option to `check_call`.

Comment: No error but the script hangs (blocking?), do I need to change this to a Popen and try to use the communicate() function

Comment: @agf let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2640/discussion-between-park-erro-and-agf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `cat` or a pipeline for this; all you need is to provide the file as standard input to the `ssh` command.  In shell, that would be

```
ssh ${USER}@${hadoopGateway} hadoop fs -put - ${targetDir}/foo < foo
```

and with the Python subprocess module it's only a tiny bit more involved:

```
foo='foo'
subprocess.check_call(['ssh',
                       os.environ['USER']+'@'+hadoopGateway,
                       'hadoop', 'fs', '-put', '-', inputArgs.targetDir+'/'+foo],
                      stdin=open(foo, 'r'))
```